# instanceof and cast to a wrapper holding generic field

Tags: java, generics

I want to write a bit universal processing class that goes through a specific tree-like data structure. The leaf value can be converted by a mapping function. The mapping is done before processing.

```java
interface Processor<T> { // In a real code it's not called like this ;)
    void addFirst(T value);
    WrappedOutput<T> next();
    boolean hasNext();

    interface WrappedOutput<T> {
        T value();
        List<ExternalParent> originalParents();
    }
}
```

But I have problem with an implementation code where it's not possible to cast to `Leaf<T>`:

```java
class ProcessorImpl<T> implements Processor<T> {
    ...
    WrappedOutput<T> next() {
        ...
        Node node = ...; // Current node
        if (node instanceof Parent parent) {
            // process nested nodes
        }
        // Compile error: Node cannot be safely cast to Leaf<T>
        else if (node instanceof Leaf<T> leaf) {
            return new WrappedOutput<>(((Leaf<T>)leaf).value(), /* other internals */);
        }
    }

    interface Node {}
    record Parent(ExternalParent parent, List<Node> children) implements Node {}
    record Leaf<T>(T value, /* other internals */) implements Node {}
}
```

I know there is a type erasure at runtime, but I actually don't care about the `T`, but due to the nature of the erasure it's not possible to simply cast to `Leaf<T>` which seems perfectly fine in nested structures that differs in type.

The only thing that works, but warns about unchecked cast is:

```java
        else if (node instanceof Leaf<?> leaf) {
            return new WrappedOutput<>(((Leaf<T>)leaf).value(), ...); // Warning about unchecked cast
        }
```

Is there any way to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Unchecked casting is the correct solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't actually care about the `T`"? You *should* care. If `node` is an instance of `Leaf<T>`, that `T` should be the same type as the `T` in `ProcessorImpl<T>`. A `ProcessImpl<String>` shouldn't be processing `Leaf<Integer>`, for example. If you've made sure that won't happen via other means, then the unchecked cast is safe and you can suppress the warning.

Comment: Thanks Louis. Sweeper: it's guaranteed the T is always correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this problem is actually fairly tough due to how Java handles generics. When you editor warns you about an unchecked cast, it means the cast is literally never checked, no exception is ever thrown. This can lead to major problems later down the line.
You can check this by having `ProcessorImpl<Integer>` and a `Leaf<String>` getting passed as node. You would think the compiler would handle this as `(Leaf<Integer>)node` which would throw an exception when it casts, but is doesn't check the generic types at all. Meaning your `Leaf<String>` with start to be treated as a `Leaf<Integer>`.
Now it is possible that this will never happen in your application, it looks as if you control the types being given via `addFirst`. In that case, ignore the warning you are fine. But if there is a chance that someone using your application might pass a non castable `Leaf` or other `Node`, then you want to have a class Instance with the constructor of `ProcessorImpl<T>` . Like so:

```
class ProcessorImpl<T> implements Processor<T> {
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    ProcessorImpl (Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then when you do your check of node, you would do something along the lines of:

```
if (node instanceof Leaf<?> leaf && clazz.isInstance(leaf.value())) { 
     return new WrappedOutput<>(clazz.cast(leaf.value()), ...); 
}
```

If you want to also allow sub types of type T look into the [isAssignableFrom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-).
This does get fairly annoying but with the current, and likely future, state of refection this will remain an issue.

Comment: We want to avoid that unsafe cast.  It is sufficient to write `if (node instanceof Leaf<?> leaf && clazz.isInstance(leaf.value())) { return new WrappedOutput<>(clazz.cast(leaf.value())); }`.

Comment: Yes this is much better then what I had, I also improperly used the instanceof pattern matching, don't know how I slipped up on that one. I have updated my answer to include this.

Comment: @VGR: This seems to be the solution! I found it for simple class, but not for ClassA<T>. I think you should add it as an answer to have the "marked" solution.

Comment: @SlovaN Thank you, but this answer appears to contain that same solution.